# What approach other than Tf-Idf could I use for text-clustering using K-Means?

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am working on a text-clustering problem. My goal is to create clusters with similar context, similar talk. I have around 40 million posts from social media. To start with I have written clustering using `K-Means` and `Tf-Idf`. The following code suggests what I am doing.

Here are main steps:

- Do some pre-processing
- Create `tfidf_matrix` while using tokenization and stemming
- Run K-Means on the `tf-idf` matrix
- Have the result

  ```
  csvRows = []
  nltk.download('stopwords')

  title = []
  synopses = []
  filename = "cc.csv"
  num_clusters = 20
  pkl_file = "doc_cluster.pkl"
  generate_pkl = False

  if len(sys.argv) == 1:
      print("Will use "+pkl_file + " to cluster")
  elif sys.argv[1] == '--generate-pkl':
      print("Will generate a new pkl file")
      generate_pkl = True


  # pre-process data
  with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
      # creating a csv reader object
      csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

      # extracting field names through first row
      fields = csvreader.next()

      # extracting each data row one by one
      duplicates = 0
      for row in csvreader:
      # removes the characters specified
      if line not in synopses:
          synopses.append(line)
          title.append(row[0])
      else:
          duplicates += 1



  stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
  stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")


  def tokenize_and_stem(text):
      # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
      tokens = [word for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(
      text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
      filtered_tokens = []
      # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
      for token in tokens:
      if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
          filtered_tokens.append(token)
      stems = [stemmer.stem(t) for t in filtered_tokens]
      return stems


  def tokenize_only(text):
      # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
      tokens = [word.lower() for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
            for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
      filtered_tokens = []
      # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
      for token in tokens:
      if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
          filtered_tokens.append(token)
      return filtered_tokens


  totalvocab_stemmed = []
  totalvocab_tokenized = []

  for i in synopses:
      # for each item in 'synopses', tokenize/stem
      allwords_stemmed = tokenize_and_stem(i)
      # extend the 'totalvocab_stemmed' list
      totalvocab_stemmed.extend(allwords_stemmed)

      allwords_tokenized = tokenize_only(i)
      totalvocab_tokenized.extend(allwords_tokenized)

  vocab_frame = pd.DataFrame(
      {'words': totalvocab_tokenized}, index=totalvocab_stemmed)

  print 'there are ' + str(vocab_frame.shape[0]) + ' items in vocab_frame'


  # define vectorizer parameters
  tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.0, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1, 3))

  tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(synopses)
  terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
  # dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)


  km = KMeans(n_clusters=10, max_iter=1000,
          verbose=1).fit(tfidf_matrix)


  clusters = km.labels_.tolist()

  # uncomment the below to save your model
  # since I've already run my model I am loading from the pickle

  if(generate_pkl):
      joblib.dump(km,  pkl_file)
      print("Generated pkl file " + pkl_file)

  km = joblib.load(pkl_file)

  clusters = km.labels_.tolist()


  films = {'title': title,  'synopsis': synopses, 'cluster': clusters, }

  total_count = len(films['synopsis'])

  csvRows = []

  for idx in range(total_count):
      csvRows.append({
      'title': films['title'][idx],
      'cluster': films['cluster'][idx]
      })

  print('Creating cluster.csv')

  with open('cluster.csv', 'w') as output:
      writer = csv.DictWriter(output, csvRows[0].keys())
      writer.writeheader()
      writer.writerows(csvRows)
      print("\ncreated cluster.csv")
  ```

The results are not very satisfactory. They are very average. What could be done to improve my clustering algorithm? I would still want to use `K-Means` but what another approach could be used in place of `Tf-Idf`?

Also, if you guys think that there is a better alternative to `K-Means`, please suggest and it even more helpful, if you could point me to sources/examples, where people have already done similar stuff.

I will always run the clustering on the volume close to 40 Million.

Comment: What about word embeddings? Is the dataset open source?

Comment: @Aditya I have prepared the data set from twitter, blogs, forums etc. Could you give an example of how to use word-embeddings?

Comment: Checkout fast.ai , Racheal Thomas workshop on this, Deep Learning.ai Andrew NG on YouTube there's a course on NLP Sequence Modelling

Comment: How did you scrapped so many tweets? Can the dataset be shared? It will help me in my ongoing internship

Comment: **Text clustering is hard.** Do not expect it to "just" work. In particular with algorithms such as k-means that make very different assumptions on your data... Word embeddings are all the rage, but I doubt they work actually much better. It's just that people *want* the results to be better. In the end, you still have 300 dimensional vectors, with plenty of anomalous documents, and k-means neither is good for high dimensions, nor for such noisy data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have now considered `HDBSCAN` algorithm for clustering but am stuck at how to create vectors from my the list of posts I have.

Comment: I don't think it will work any better, because of the distance functions not working well enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will likely see an improvement by using an algorithm like GloVe in place of Tf-Idf. Like Tf-Idf, GloVe represents a group of words as a vector. Unlike Tf-Idf, which is a Bag-of-Words approach, GloVe and similar techniques preserve the order of words in a tweet. Knowing what word comes before or after a word of interest is valuable information for assigning meaning. [This Article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/) runs through different techniques and gives a good description of each one. Also, [This Script](https://www.kaggle.com/tunguz/bi-gru-cnn-poolings-gpu-kernel-version) on Kaggle shows how to use pretrained word vectors to represent tweets.

For your clustering, I recommend checking out Density-Based clustering. K-means is a decent all-purpose algorithm, but it's a partitional method and depends on assumptions that might not be true, such as clusters being roughly equal in size. This is almost certainly not the case. [This Blog](https://recast.ai/blog/introduction-text-clustering/) has a great discussion on clustering for text. If you go with Density-Based and you use Python, I highly recommend [HDBSCAN](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan) by Leland McInnes.

Good luck!

Comment: This all looks good. I have tried `HDBSCAN` (I am working with python) with a few sample examples on their documentation site. Could you point me to a good example that uses `GloVe` rather than `Tf-Idf` as an input?

Comment: Also, is there a limit to the max posts that can be passed to `HDBSCAN`? When I pass tf_idf matrix as `c.fit(tfidf_matrix)` for a huge document set, it throws `memory error`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using n_grams.

### n-grams

**n-grams** is a feature extraction technique for language based data. It segments the Strings such that roots of words can be found, ignoring verb endings, pluralities etc...

The segmentation works as follows:

The String: Hello World

2-gram: "He", "el", "ll", "lo", "o ", " W", "Wo", "or", "rl", "ld"
3-gram: "Hel", "ell", "llo", "lo ", "o W", " Wo", "Wor", "orl", "rld"
4-gram: "Hell", "ello", "llo ", "lo W", "o Wo", " Wor", "Worl", "orld"

Thus in your example, if we use 4-grams, truncations of the word Hello would appear to be the same. And this similarity would be captured by your features.

Comment: I am ready using stemming in the code I shared

Comment: Is there a way I could use `GloVe` / `gensim` here?

Answer (score 0):

K-means require a matrix, in order to improve the performance you should be sure about how you have created it.

TF-IDF is a matrix, Word2Vec
What could be done to improve my clustering algorithm? 
Hyperparameters should be tuned like bigrams.

I would still want to use K-Means but what another approach could be used in place of TF-IDF?

Word2Vec/CBOW